# How do I compare how much variation there is between data sets?

Tags: statistics, order-statistics

I have a large number (~1000) of number sets containing 8 numerical elements. Here's an example:

```
A = (5, 10, 9, 11, 4, 8, 8, 9)
B = (14, 10, 12, 19, 20, 13, 8, 13)
C = (8, 8, 8, 9, 8, 8, 9, 10)
```

I want to determine which sets vary the least. I have already calculated mean, standard deviation and variance for each set but I am not sure how to apply these calculated values to my question. Can I simply group the sets in order of increasing variance and say that the lower the variance, the more consistent the numbers within that set are?

In case you are interested: the practical application is that each set represents a measurement of a biological system across 8 control samples; the goal is to prioritize which measurements are least likely to give wildly different values unless altered by experimental conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variance is invariant under addition.  That is  $\{9,11\}$ and $\{90,92\}$ will have the same variance although they have different means. [if you subtract the mean from each they will be $\{-1,1\}$]

However, variance is not invariant under multiplication.  Consider $\{9,11\}$ and $\{90,110\}$.  These do not have the same variance, but, if you divide by the mean both sets become $\{0.9,1.1\}$ which *do* have the same variance.

You need to decide, based on your context, which measure is more relevant for you.

Comment: Wow! This is a great answer. You answered my question, helped me solve my current problem and gave me insight into a future problem I didn't realize I had. Thank you!

Comment: My pleasure, glad to help.